# How to force 204 rest API to return content?

Tags: php, json, api, rest

I know that `204` means that the server has understood the request but there is no content available. But I think is wrong prevent to the developer return a json message like this: 
`return json_encode(array("mex" => "no content"));`

What I need is return also a json when the API return `204` in the header. I don't want use `200` in this case 'cause this means that there is a content returned.
Also the `404` is not appropriate 'cause this means the resource doesn't exits.

Anyidea to do this?
This is my code:

```
http_response_code(204);
return json_encode(array("mex" => "no content"));
```

Comment: Your json string is content, so you should be using 200. If you want to use 204, then you can't return content of any kind.

Comment: @vascowhite I know this, but I want tell to who use the API through the `204` that there is no content.

Comment: That's what the 204 indicates, you don't need to explain further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. [The HTTP specification](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.2.5) states that:

> The 204 response MUST NOT include a message-body, and thus is always terminated by the first empty line after the header fields.

Attempting to include content in a 204 response will cause many HTTP clients to malfunction. If you want to include a message with your response, you will need to use a response code other than 204.

Comment: That's up to you. If you want to be picky about it, read the specification to see what is most appropriate; if you don't, use 200.

Comment: your opinion about this?

Comment: I don't know anything about your API, so I don't have an opinion on it.

Comment: No I mean, if you need to return a json and also empty content which code you'll use?

Comment: That's a contradiction. If you're returning JSON data, you're not returning an empty response.